# How do I acquire health insurance for a 2 week trip to Romania

Tags: health, insurance

I am traveling to Bucharest Romania for a 2-week vacation. I'm wondering if health insurance is a good idea

Comment: What country are you coming from?

Comment: Welcome, James. You've actually asked two questions: how to get insurance, and whether it's a good idea. For the first one, responding to Zach Lipton would help, as would telling the results of your own research. The second asks for opinions, which is not the format of this site.

Comment: Unless you are very rich, having a good health insurance is always good. When traveling, adding a travel insurance is good, as you will be covered against costs which come from being out of your country.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is a good idea to have health insurance all the time when you travel abroad, but it's not mandatory to enter Romania.

Comment: Hey, do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Marm Mayo, I'm romanian. And I know this is not mandatory.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? Maybe someone should give an explanation or try asking before downvoting....

Comment: "Mark".  I didn't downvote, but it could be for the same reason I asked for a source.  You didn't mention in your answer how you knew that. Nobody else knows you're Romanian, and we like to have sources on here to help people be more confident in the answer.  Perhaps you could edit your answer to include this and any other extra information?